# Why statsmodels seasonal_decompose gives residuals as a scatterplot?

Tags: python, plot, statsmodels

Why statsmodels seasonal_decompose gives residuals as a scatterplot?

```
def plot_decomposition(series):
    result = seasonal_decompose(series, model='multiplicative', period=30)
    print(result.trend)
    print(result.seasonal)
    print(result.resid)
    print(result.observed)
    figure = result.plot()
    figure.set_size_inches(14, 6)
    plt.savefig(save_path + 'FB_dec.svg')
    figure.suptitle("Decomposition of Microsoft corporations's adjusted close", y=0.99, x=0.52)
    plt.show()

df = pd.read_csv('MSFT.csv', header=0, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)
series = df['Adj Close']
plot_decomposition(series)
```

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzWbG.png)

Comment: It is not a scatter plot.  It just has markers and no line connecting the residuals.  This is an aesthetic choice. You can override the appearance by changing the properties of the line on the appropriate axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
      from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
 current_date=datetime.datetime.now()
 start_date=datetime.datetime(current_date.year,1,1)
 df = pdr.get_data_yahoo("MSFT",start_date,current_date).reset_index()

 decomposition=sm.tsa.seasonal_decompose(x=df['High'],model='additive',      extrapolate_trend='freq', period=30)
 decomposition.plot()
 plt.show()

 decomposition_trend=decomposition.trend
 ax= decomposition_trend.plot(figsize=(14,2))
 ax.set_xlabel('Date')
 ax.set_ylabel('Trend of time series')
 ax.set_title('Trend values of the time series')
 plt.show()

 decomposition_residual=decomposition.resid
 ax= decomposition_residual.plot(figsize=(14,2))
 ax.set_xlabel('Date')
 ax.set_ylabel('Residual of time series')
 ax.set_title('Residual values of the time series')
 plt.show()
```